# Is it needed to normalize data before rule model extraction algorithms like ID3?

Tags: classification, model-selection, normalization, association-rules

I will use naive Bayes or decision tree that gives rule model both. Is is necessary to normalize data before working with such algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have nominal valued features, then there is no need to normalize data for both Naive Bayes Classifier (NBC) and Decision Trees. This is because we are dealing with discrete variables (nominal or ordinal) and computing probablity (for NBC) or gain ratio (for Decision Trees) becomes easier.

If you have continuous features, then, I suggest applying NBC and Decision Trees e.g. ID3 or C4.5 for the two cases; the first case is based on the normalized version of features while the second one is based on the original feature. Check the results and use the better representation !!